# Issue with geometry rendering - SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnnode, scnmaterial

I have a set of SceneKit custom geometries. When rendered, and under certain viewing angles, they seem as if they are transparent (one can see through their outer surface and see what is behind, or one can see the inner surfaces). Their material transparency and the opacity of the encapsulating nodes are all correctly set. Also, some of them intersect and their intersection is fully visible. Any thought as to what might be the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Are the materials custom as well?

Comment: Thanks - no, just modifying the SCNGeometry's firstMaterial property with `viewGeometry.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents =` (color alpha set to 1).

Comment: There might be an issue with the direction of the polygon normals. There may be a way to deal with that in SceneKit but the best approach would be to insure allignment when creating the geometry.

Comment: Thanks - yes, have looked into normals also. So far nothing found on that front but I'll keep checking. Btw, just to make sure: by alignment you mean normals should all have appropriate normals and share the same normal direction?

Comment: Each polygon of your geometry has a normal, it is perpendicular to the plane of the poly. Your geometry will work best when the normal of each poly points outward from the interior of the geometry. In Cinema 4D, for instance, you can show these normals and execute a command that will align them (point them all outward). Basically, the normal defines which is the outside of the poly. Depending on how you construct the geometry, some of the polys' normals may be pointing inward which could lead to some of the issues you describe.

Comment: Ok - we're on the same page. So yes, checking for that too (technically all normals should be correct but maybe a bug crept in). Thanks again.